# Linux find command equivalent for makefile on windows

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I just installed MinGW and I was going to ejecute make to compile a project and I realized the makefile I got worked perfectly on Ubuntu but obviusly not on windows. This is what I got

```
G++ ?= g++
C_FLAGS = 0

BIN ?= program.exe

HDR_DIR ?= ./headers
OBJ_DIR ?= OBJ
SRC_DIR ?= SRC

FILES ?= $(basename $(notdir $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name "*.cc")))

SRC ?= $(addsuffix .cc, $(FILES))
OBJ ?= $(addsuffix .o, $(FILES))


$(BIN): $(addprefix ./OBJ/, $(OBJ))
    $(G++) -g $^ -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
    $(G++) -I$(HDR_DIR) -g -c -o $@ $<
```

So i searched a little bit and I think the only line that needs to be changed is where I define the FILES variable. I've tried with:

```
FILES ?= $(basename $(notdir $(shell $(SRC_DIR) /s "*.cc")))
```

But I think I'm not getting how dir works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using gnu make file wildcard - then it will be portable:

Works like this:

```
FILES=$(wildcard subdir/*.c)
```

For your makefile example:

```
FILES ?= $(basename $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cc)))
```

Comment: Well.. It worked like a charm! I'll investigate that wildcard thing, thanks a lot!

Comment: Its a versatile function - you can also use it to check if a file exists: `ifneq (,$(wildcard somefolder/somefile.c))`. If you possibly can, its a good idea to stay away from using OS specific functions (you can't always do that), but if you have to you can wrap them in your own makefile functions https://coderwall.com/p/cezf6g/define-your-own-function-in-a-makefile then you can create a set of functions for linux and the same for windows (or other OS) and put them into different makefiles (e.g. win_make.mk, lin_make.mk) and then include the one you want based on your OS :)